# Optimization using rbinom with NAs and mcmapply

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to sample data from a binomial distribution using two numeric vectors, both of around 8 million elements each. They look like this:

```
b = runif(n = 8000000, min = 0, max = 1)
d=rpois( 8000000, lambda =0.1)
```

I want to apply this function for every element of b and d

```
rbinom_NA = function(x , y) {
  result = rbinom(n = x,
                  size = 1,
                  prob = y) 
  
  if (length(result) == 0)
    return(NA)
  return(result)
}
```

I do it with mcmapply. You can see how long it takes for me on my computer.

```
rbinom_result = vector(mode = "list", length = 8000000)
rbinom_result = mcmapply(
  d,
  b,
  FUN = rbinom_NA, 
  mc.cores = detectCores()-1) #run on Ubuntu, 32 cores and 64Gb memory
# system.time result:
#  user  system elapsed 
# 90.631 116.584 154.353
```

Then I calculate the mean for every element of the previous result:

```
final_result= vapply(rbinom_result, mean, FUN.VALUE = 1)
# system.time result:
# user  system elapsed 
# 23.372   0.050  23.412
```

How can I make these two bits of code run faster?
Thank you in advance for your help.

**Edit:** I need to calculate the mean of every element of rbinom_result separately, which might be NA or a variable number of integers depending on the number passed to `rbinom_NA()` by the vector d. So in reality I'd make this calculation with d vectors created from different lambdas, so the rbinom_result now looks like this:

```
#if lamb=0.01
head(rbinom_result)
$pos1
[1] NA

$pos2
[1] NA

$pos3
[1] NA
#etc

#if lamb=5
head(rbinom_result)

 $pos1
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 
 $pos2
 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
 
 $pos3
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
# etc
```

and then in the end I want to collate final_result into a data frame that contains the results for every value of lambda (lambdas are columns, with 8e6 rows). So the whole thing looks like this:

```
library(parallel)
lambdas = c(0.01,5)#just two here, will be more
final_result = vector(mode = "list", length = length(lambdas))

for (lamb in lambdas){
b = runif(n = 8e6, min = 0, max = 1)
d=rpois( 8e6, lambda =lamb)

rbinom_NA = function(x , y) {
  result = rbinom(n = x,
                  size = 1,
                  prob = y) 
  
  if (length(result) == 0)
    return(NA)
  return(result)
}


rbinom_result = vector(mode = "list", length = 8e6)
rbinom_result = mcmapply(
  d,
  b,
  FUN = rbinom_NA, 
  mc.cores = detectCores()-1) #run on Ubuntu, 32 cores and 64Gb memory

names(rbinom_result) = paste0("pos",1:8e6)

final_result[[as.character(lamb)]]= vapply(rbinom_result, mean, FUN.VALUE = 1)

}
final_result = do.call("cbind", final_result)
```

In the end:

```
 head(final_result)
     0.01         5
pos1   NA 0.0000000
pos2   NA 0.7142857
pos3   NA 0.0000000
pos4   NA 0.6000000
pos5   NA 1.0000000
pos6   NA 0.1666667
#etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `final_result` for each `lambda` with a single command involving `rbinom`:

```
b <- runif(8e6)
d <- rpois(8e6, 0.1)
system.time(final_result <- rbinom(length(b), d, b)/d)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.327   0.058   0.384
```

This works because the the following two lines follow the same distribution for atomic `x` and `y`:

```
mean(rbinom(x, 1, y))
rbinom(1, x, y)/x
```

The difference is that the second is vectorized for equal-length vectors of `x` and `y` simply by changing the `n` (first) argument in `rbinom` from `1` to `length(x)`. Also, if `x = 0`, `rbinom(1, x, y)/x` is `NA`, so the NA behavior is maintained.

For multiple `lambda`:

```
library(parallel)

fSim <- function(lambda, n){
  b <- runif(n)
  d <- rpois(n, lambda)
  return(rbinom(length(b), d, b)/d)
}

lambdas <- c(0.1, 5)
system.time(final_result <- mcmapply(fSim, lambdas, 8e6, mc.cores = min(length(lambdas), detectCores() - 1)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.340   0.931   2.031
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my edit for more details on what I want to do.

Comment: @MartaPérezAlcántara I see. Still easily doable. Do you need to keep `rbinom_result` or just `final_result`? I ask because you can get `final_result` faster by getting the aggregate of each element of `rbinom_result` directly.

Comment: I just need ```final_result```

Comment: @MartaPérezAlcántara I fixed my answer. Does the behavior match now?